# How to create child from Edit Text in Firebase

Tags: android

I created a simple application in Firebase . I want to add child which take input from the Edit Text .
This work fine .

```
       mDatabase = 
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("SubMenu");
```

but when I want to create from Edit Text then it create random child not from Edit Text.
Like:

```
       mDatabase=
      FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(title.getText().to
     String());
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ref.push() ? If yes then it will create new list with unique key everytime..

Comment: So how it possible if i want to add child from edit text and if i not use push()

Comment: You can directly call setValue on ref object but its drawback would be if your edittext value is same then existing value would be overwritten.

Comment: can you explain with simple example

Comment: Let's say you have created path in Firebase as root -> edittext1 and if you setValue to edittext1 again then its value will be overwritten on Firebase. So for making new child you have to make sure that your edittext value is unique everytime

Comment: mDatabase=
      FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(title.getText().to
     String()); why this child not created while taking the child name from edittext i am not using push()

Comment: @wikiwi use this .Child(title.gettext().toString()).setValue()

Comment: In simplw word when i write like mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference.child("menu"); so it work but i want to add the childe name from the edittext as i write as menu so i want to add this name from the edittext

Comment: Can you share your code with me. I will try my best to help you.